# «Мне очень странно». Статус и употребление выражения

Tags: грамотная-речь, словосочетания, наречия

*— Не нам рассуждать, Лина Федоровна. Мы здесь не наследники. Вот **мне очень странно, почему** Сергей занимает три комнаты, а Анна одну, — очень, весьма странно!*
[Б. Пильняк. Наследники](https://books.google.ee/books?id=qSXSAAAAQBAJ&pg=PP7&lpg=PP7&dq=%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%B5%20%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8C%20%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE&source=bl&ots=a8V56YrAQ8&sig=JH4GhwBmv_qRqfjOllYbg5TjxYI&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjj196srZzfAhWJs4sKHfZDCTk4ChDoATALegQIAxAB#v=onepage&q=%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%B5%20%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8C%20%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE&f=false)

*— (…) Конечно, это не значит, что вы кому-то должны крупную сумму и кредитор шантажирует вас, грозясь похитить Надю. Но, видите ли, **мне очень странно, если** некая банда, которой вы ничего не должны, сначала требует у вас деньги, а потом, если их не получит, собирается похитить вашу дочь.*
[Ф. Ромм. В сетях](https://books.google.ee/books?id=_-dIDwAAQBAJ&pg=PT53&lpg=PT53&dq=%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%B5%20%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8C%20%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE&source=bl&ots=kTxmf0qHEY&sig=VUGMCEGgGDlEYYfpmoGoZ0Rxaeg&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwijhJPH6KHfAhVhlYsKHYBZATw4ChDoATACegQICBAB#v=onepage&q=%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%B5%20%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8C%20%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE&f=false)

Мне очень больно; мне страшно; мне очень обидно — тут всё правильно, вопросов не возникает.
А вот слова **мне очень странно** кажутся мне в чём-то ошибочными, какими-то "дискомфортными", в указанных предложениях — особенно.
Или все нормально, и мои сомнения напрасны?

Comment: Зафиксировано [в словарях](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE&all=x).

Comment: Спасибо, я видела эту словарную статью. Но в ней:  **мне странно, что...** и **странно, как...** А в предложениях: **мне очень странно, почему...** и **мне очень странно, если...** Или нет разницы в употреблении? Или я что-то неправильно озвучила в вопросе?

Answer (score 2):

Примерно то же, что "мне вкусно"? Это выражение тоже считается неграмотным, хотя я не понимаю почему.

Мне больно ~ я чувствую (испытываю) боль.
Мне обидно ~ я чувствую (испытываю) обиду.
Мне странно ~ я чувствую (испытываю)... что?!

Но так говорят, причем все, и с этим надо считаться.

А вот цитата из классика:

*Кумушка, мне странно это...*

Comment: Можно испытывать странность, как боль, как вкус, как обиду?

Comment: Нельзя, об этом я и говорю. Но все равно: "мне странно" -- так говорят. Можно найти много подобных нелогичностей в языке, и специалисты, наверно, могут находить им объяснения, но наша задача гораздо проще: говорят так или нет? И если да, то все "логические" доводы против не имеют никакого значения.

Comment: В ходу много украинизмов. «Наша задача» будет такой же, не возникать? Заодно спрошу про волнующийся математизм — математический символ ( ~ ). Это зачем или к чему?

Comment: Это означает соответствие. А украинизмы при чем?

Comment: Знаю что это означает, не знаю зачем это здесь. Это ж не цитата, которую не тронь. Вопрос был: «возникать или возникать не очень» (украинизм — как пример)?

Comment: Цитата из классика (будем считать, что только сейчас её заметил) не к месту, с ней странностей не произойдёт: она не заканчивается на слове «странно». «Это странно» — совсееееем не «мне это странно».

Answer (score 2):

Из словаря на Грамоте.ру:

СТРАННО. I. нареч. к Странный. С. выглядеть. С. одеваться. II. в функц. безл. сказ. Вызывает недоумение, удивление. **Мне с., что ты споришь с этим.** С., как она попала сюда. С., что он не позвонил.

И мне странно, что все это случилось только сейчас, а не гораздо раньше. [Андрей Вознесенский. На виртуальном ветру (1998)]

Выражение используется очень часто, таких примеров много.

**Но почему оно может показаться дискомфортным и чем отличается от выражений "мне страшно", "мне интересно"?**

Странно — это не особое чувство внутри нас. Фактически это тоже недоумение (удивление), но при этом оно вызвано  необычностью, странностью чего-либо, причем  речь идет **о внешней странности.**

Странно видеть, необычно видеть — эти выражения похожи по значению. Но мы не говорим : мне необычно, а говорим: **для меня** необычно. Речь идет не о внутреннем чувстве "странности", а **о странности внешнего явления** (оно для меня необычно, странно).

Итак, не существует чувства "странности" —  в этом и заключен определенный дискомфорт.  **Поэтому выражение "мне странно" может казаться противоречивым, а "для меня странно" воспринимается нормально.**

Тем менее выражение  "мне странно" вполне нормативно (перенос значения  по смежности характерен для языка).

Comment: Не о наречии вопрос, —  о форме «мне очень странно», в то время как иные формы (для меня странно, по мне так очень странно, просто странно) так не воспринимаются?

Comment: Объяснение дано в дополнении к основному ответу.

Answer (score 1):

Где и кто определил, что "мне" сочетается только с ощущениями и эмоциями? Возьмите "мне все равно", "мне известно" и т. п. Думаю, законов здесь нет, что-то закрепилось в языке, что-то нет. Если "мне странно" попало в словари, значит это корректно.

"Мне странно, почему..." — на мой взгляд, перебор. Тут смешалось и "мне странно, что" и "я хотел бы знать, почему".

Второе предложение (с "мне очень странно, если...") вообще выглядит как результат неудачного перевода. Ситуация странная объективно, там еще есть слова "видите ли", так причем тут "мне"? Ситуация уже имеет место, зачем ставить "если"? Я бы написал: Странно, что (или когда) некая банда, которой вы ничего не должны, сначала требует у вас деньги..."

Comment: Думаю, мне надо подправить вопрос, чтобы стало понятнее: _мне очень странно, почему..._ и _мне очень странно, если..._  Дайте совет, пожалуйста.

Comment: Да, заголовок очень общий: «Мне очень странно» ― статус выражения.

Comment: Посмотрите, мне кажется, что ТАК лучше. Спасибо.

Comment: Что такое "статус" в данном случае? Законное/незаконное?

Comment: Ну, скорее всего, правильно/неправильно, в особенности ― в указанном контексте.

Comment: То есть вы сомневатесь в допустимости вообще,  а если все-таки оно допустимо, то вопрос в том, как его употреблять? Заголовок не идеальный, но как все это коротко выразить, сам не знаю, поэтому не буду придираться :)